# How are Windows GUI control ids created?

Tags: c#, windows, user-interface, controls, ui-automation

In Windows, for each and every control like (for every dialog, window, textbox and checkbox etc) a control id will be given.

How is this control id created? Can two applications in Windows can have same control ids? Is there any way to manually set Windows control ids?

Comment: Is that even true? I think controls can choose to use IDs or not. A window handle is enough to identify a control.

Comment: It is not.  It is normally only set for dialogs created from a dialog template.  It can be changed later with SetWindowLongPtr, GWLP_ID.

Comment: There are multiple types of control IDs.  Automation ID is what you want to set.  Are you using WinForms, WPF, or Win32 for your app?  The answer to "is there any way to manually set windows control ids" will be different for each framework.  And automation IDs don't have to be globally unique - they just have to be unique in a given scope to be useful, since you just need a unique path down the tree to identify a particular control.  See this for .Net GUI apps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa349646.aspx

Comment: @Hans: SetWindowLongPtr(GWLP_ID) is only valid for child windows, per MSDN. Top-level windows, dialogs or otherwise, do not have control IDs at all; that slot of the window data is (was, historically, not sure if the impl is still that way) used for the HMENU. (A child window created from a dialog template can have a control ID, but AFAIK it's not set by the dialog code; it would be completely up to the owning code to set it with SetWindowLongPtr.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The control ID is one of the parameters passed to the `CreateWindow` function. If the control was created from a dialog template, then the dialog manager gets the control ID from the dialog template. It is quite common for two controls to have the same ID. For example, most `Cancel` buttons will have the control ID `IDCANCEL`.

Comment: I don't see what parameter to CreateWindow is the control ID.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Ah, found it.  You use hMenu.  Found it on this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645478(v=vs.85).aspx in the remarks section.

Comment: It is quite **uncommon** for two controls in the same window to have the same ID. For example the [GetDlgItem function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645481(v=vs.85).aspx) depends on that.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what Raymond wrote:

It's perfectly legal for a window to create to child windows (aka controls) and give them the same ControlId. The only problem is that you won't be able to uniquely retrieve a control by its id (using `GetDlgItem()`). If you are not interested in manipulating a control at runtime (such as a static label), you don't have to care giving it a unique control id. Just give it 0xFFFF).

An it's certainly legal (and usual) the same control id for different controls/child windows in different application or parent windows (eg IDCANCEL or IDOK for buttons). GetDlgItem() retrieves the control of one given parent window.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the information in the other answers:

> In windows for each and every control like (for every dialog,window,textbox and checkbox etc) a control id will be given

That's not actually quite true: top-level windows - such as app windows, and dialogs, don't actually have a control ID at all. Only child windows can have control IDs.

(Top-level windows use that parameter of CreateWindow to indicate the HMENU for the window instead - so only top-level windows can have menubars.)

It's really up to the app developer to decide how to assign and use the IDs. Usually they are used with GetDlgItem(), which looks for a HWND with a given ID with a parent HWND, so in that case, the IDs only need to be unique within that parent. If a developer doesn't need to look up a control at runtime, it can give it any ID, traditionally -1 is used there.

Some frameworks don't use control IDs at all and just keep track of the HWNDs as they are created.

Comment: Using WinSpy++ I looked at the top-level window for calc.exe and it has a control ID.  I know it is the top level window because its parent window ID is "00000000".

Comment: That value is likely actually the window's menu handle; windows have either a menu handler or a control ID depending on whether they are top-level or child windows. The Spy++ tool from Microsoft uses the same line in its version of the Window Properties dialog to display this value, using the label "Control ID" by default, changing it to "Menu Handle" if the window is top-level and the value is non-null. Likely WinSpy++ isn't being as diligent in its use of labels here.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  However, I am able to pass the said Control ID to `GetDlgItem()` and obtain a meaningful hwnd in return.  I am thinking that if `GetDlgItem()` honors the data item as a valid Control ID, then it must be one.

Comment: What HWND are you passing as the hwnd param to GetDlgItem? You probably don't want to be using GetDlgItem to find top-level windows; it's designed to find a child window by ID in a parent dialog where _you_ have assigned all the IDs yourself, so you know what you'll get back. Most top-level HWNDs will have this value as null or a HMENU value, which is effectively random. What are you _really_ trying to do here? There's probably a better way to do that, instead of [mis]using GetDlgItem :)

Comment: I developed a small application that drives calc.exe.  When I looked into calc.exe using WinSpy++, the only unique id I could find for each button was its Control ID; e.g., button "1" is 0x83, "+" is 0x5D.  Then, I enumerated all child windows for calc.exe (136 of them) and searched for these Control ID's and found their hwnd values.  I use the hwnd's to do SendMessage calls.  It works.  I know Control IDs may not be unique or may be null, but in case of calc.exe they do the job.  I could not find any other way than GetDlgItem to retrieve the hwnd for a given Control ID. Thank you again.

Comment: << the only unique id I could find for each button >> -- those buttons are child windows, so they can have control IDs. My comment above is that the top-level calc.exe application window doesn't have a control ID. You should be OK when running against that specific version of calc.exe - but in Windows 10 (8?) calc gets an update and looks like it no longer uses child windows! For doing automation, you might also want to look at the "UI Automation" API, which allows you to access UI elements of compatible applications whether or not they are using HWNDs or some other technique.

Comment: > "but in Windows 10 (8?) calc gets an update..." Exactly. I know my solution is not perfect and is only proven for Windows 7.  So you are saying that the Control ID that WinSpy++ shows for the top level window is really the handle for the menu.  I will keep this in mind.  I had searched for UI Automation API earlier and the MSDN links that came up had Windows XP references; could not find anything recent. Thanks again.  BTW: Here's that project of mine: https://github.com/sabuncu/TestWinAPI

Comment: Interesting; some of the MSDN docs that list where UIAutomation is supported only list up to Windows 7; but there _have_ been [more additions to it in Windows 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh437316(v=vs.85).aspx) and it's still supported in Windows 10.

Comment: "So you are saying that the Control ID that WinSpy++ shows for the top level window is really the handle for the menu." - that's what I suspect is happening. Try with the official Microsoft Spy++ (part of Visual Studio) app, and see what it reports - it reports it as "Menu Handle" instead of "Control ID" for top-level windows, if it's non-null.

Comment: Thank you so much for the up-to-date UI Automation link. This has been a very useful exchange, much appreciated. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers:

Although control's ID can be the same, you'd better make it unique. Control reports events to their parent window with its id and hwnd. In the parent's message loop we generally use id to identify the control, in this case, if you want different event handling, use different id for each control.