# Python Pywinauto no control_identifiers or children in application

Tags: python, pywinauto

Hey everyone I'm having a hard time automating a specific application. Using pywinauto I want to automate clicking, keypresses, etc. to login and benchmark this application but for some reason I can't find any control identifiers for this application. Am I doing something wrong? I used this same method with task manager and other applications and this works fine.

Important Documentation:
[Code Example](http://pywinauto.googlecode.com/hg/pywinauto/docs/getting_started.html)
[Class Doc](https://pywinauto.googlecode.com/hg/pywinauto/docs/code/pywinauto.application.html)

Code:

```
import pywinauto
app = pywinauto.application.Application()
window_handle = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(title = u'Name of application')
#print window_handle #makes sure to see if handle exists
window = app.window_(handle = window_handle[0])
print window.Children() #first approach
print app.top_window_()._ctrl_identifiers() #second approach
```

Output:

```
>>>[]
>>>{}
```

Has this happened to anyone before and has found a way around it? Should I just resort to using pywin32 instead? Thank you!

Comment: `pywinauto` is already based on Win32 API, so pyWin32 is not a silver bullet. Please provide more details in such cases: which GUI framework is used for building the app, is it 64-bit, is your Python 64-bit etc.

Comment: The application was written in C# but the home page before you reached the real application was written with something else that i've never seen before. Maybe VB, Maybe even COBOL!

Comment: Okay, we may get back here when UIA-extensions for pywinauto will be ready. Or you can experiment with UIAutomationCore.dll and comtypes package. This is a starting point: https://github.com/billagee/test-polyglot/blob/master/printDesktopUiaElementName/ms-ui-automation-com-api/python/comtypes/print_desktop_uia_element_name.py UIA can get FrameworkId for any AutomationElement. See `CurrentFrameworkId` property.

Comment: His code is interesting. I reached another wall where the only windows I can find in the application were all [DialogWrappers](https://pywinauto.googlecode.com/hg/pywinauto/docs/code/pywinauto.controls.win32_controls.html?highlight=win32_controls#pywinauto.controls.win32_controls) and I can't manipulate them or get any information out of them that's useful.

Comment: There is a branch for UIA future features in pywinauto: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/tree/UIA But I'm planning to make experimental release this autumn probably. I think you don't have so much time. :)

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the application does have control identifiers I just needed to get past the first screen. Using `window.TypeKeys("{TAB}{TAB}{ENTER}")` I was able to navigate past the home screen with keypresses and into the actual application which had all the identifiers.

Useful Links if anyone encounters this problem.

[What is a control Identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421525/how-are-windows-gui-control-ids-created)